# MVC ASPX To Razor - Register webcontrol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, web-controls

I converted my MVC 3 project from to aspx to razor, having a problem with this line:
ASPX:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="WebControlCaptcha" Assembly="WebControlCaptcha" %>
```

Razor:

```
@{
Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="WebControlCaptcha" Assembly="WebControlCaptcha";
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Razor does not support web controls.  You should not use web controls at all in MVC.  Use partial views or child actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put, in the web.config inside Views folder, the following key:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="WebControlCaptcha" namespace="WebControlCaptcha" tagPrefix="cc1" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniele, I got this error: Unrecognized configuration section system.web/controls.

Comment: Thanks a million Danniele.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the application pool was set to use integrated pipeline mode with .NET Framework 2.0. The CAPTCHA image would not generate. I changed the application pool to use "Classic" while leaving the .NET Framework option the same and this fixed the image generation issue.